# NEXTJS, MONGODB - updateOne does not work?

Tags: mongodb, next.js

I try to implement updateOne function of Mongodb on NEXTJS.
But it does not update, from console.log(req.body) can get the information.

```
handler.patch(async (req, res) => {
  if (!req.user) {
    res.status(401).end();
    return;
  }
  const { name, bio } = req.body;
  await req.db.collection('users').updateOne(
    { _id: req.user._id },
    {
      $set: {
        ...(name && { name }),
        bio: bio || '',
      },
    },
  );
  res.json({ user: { name, bio } });
});
```

Please help to verify what I miss????
Thank you very much in advance.

Below is the result from console.log(req.body);

```
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="name"

Firstname Lastname
------WebKitFormBoundaryPwuAfw4FvUzDe8uP
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="bio"

xx
------WebKitFormBoundaryPwuAfw4FvUzDe8uP--
```

So I'm not sure that I get the right information.

Comment: you dont use mongoose?

Comment: Is the `_id` you got from `req.user` the same type as what's stored in the database?

Comment: @thammada , _id it is the same (from console.log). I'm not sure my function or syntax are incorrect?

Comment: @Ifaruki , I use MongoDB driver.

Comment: Somehow the `body` didn't get parsed by next.js